# Big brackets and text inside the brackets

Tags: brackets

I was trying to make something similar to this image

[image]

However if I try to do it with the function \left {  \right } in my document

[image]

It looks really bad. Can you give me some recomendation to improve the look of the equation?

Comment: First of all, you need a backslash before curly brackets to interpret them as a brackets, like this `\left\{...\right\}`. Secondly, you would probably need a `\parbox` to restrict the width of the text you put.

Comment: No No. The best answer with more score it is of @egreg. Please, can you give the check mark to egreg? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I added another option using `bracket` package with the command `\Set`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
  I^{\pm}(p) = \Set{ q\in \mathscr{M} | \begin{array}{c}
    \exists \: \text{future- (past-)directed time-like}\\
    \text{curve $\lambda(x)$ such that}\\
     \lambda(0)=p; \quad \lambda(1)=q
  \end{array}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer another font I suggest the use of the combination `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` that it is similar to your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  I^{\pm}(p) = \Set{ q\in \mathscr{M} | \begin{array}{c}
    \exists \: \text{future- (past-)directed time-like}\\
    \text{curve $\lambda(x)$ such that}\\
     \lambda(0)=p; \quad \lambda(1)=q
  \end{array}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `\middle` and a `tabular`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\[
I^{\pm}(p)=\left\{ q\in\mathcal{M} \;\middle|\;
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
$\exists$ future- (past-)directed time-like \\
\quad curve $\lambda(x)$ such that \\
\quad $\lambda(0)=p$; $\lambda(1)=q$
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me very much....for this post. There is a small, to the start of your code, `l` instead of capital letter `I`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Fixed, thanks.